# Create hardlink/symlink from windows on unix networkshare

Tags: python, linux, windows, symlink, hardlink

Is it possible to create a hardlink/symlink on networkshare that is on linux but from windows environemnt which has access to that share?

Lets say that I have a file on networkshare:

\share\test.txt

and I want to create hardlink (or symlink) here:

\share\links\test.txt

But I can only use python which is installed on windows machine with access to that share.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -1):

Not over cifs (windows share) protocol. From the windows machine viewpoint the symlinks don't even exist, they appear and behave as normal files, and windows has no way to create or even differentiate them when using this protocol.

You could use `paramiko` to automate a ssh session to the linux machine and create the symlinks using this method.

Comment: When did we start downvoting correct answers with no comment?